# SVG file used as background img in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to use a figma selfmade SVG I saved it on my laptop as VisaCard.SVG and I was able to open it in the editor but it has an HTML format.
My main goal is to use this as SVG as background to write text over it.

I looked online how to use a SVG as background but so far I just find examples where  the svg is used as link, so I will like to know how can I achieve this with a SVG file. Or could someone help me understand how to implement mine own SVG as URL?
I was following this example from https://codepen.io/rmcguinn/pen/JpVwBp, however the sintax of the SVG is different.

```
Example from <https://codepen.io/rmcguinn/pen/JpVwBp>

.Inner-wrap {
  background-color: red;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%25' height='100%25' viewBox='0 0 1600 800'%3E%3Cg %3E%3Cpolygon fill='%230d1838' points='1600%2C160 0%2C460 0%2C350 1600%2C50'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%230e315d' points='1600%2C260 0%2C560 0%2C450 1600%2C150'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%230f4981' points='1600%2C360 0%2C660 0%2C550 1600%2C250'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%231062a6' points='1600%2C460 0%2C760 0%2C650 1600%2C350'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23117aca' points='1600%2C800 0%2C800 0%2C750 1600%2C450'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: auto 147%;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 13px;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
}
```

MINE SVG

```
<svg width="240" height="144" viewBox="0 0 240 144" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g clip-path="url(#clip0_105_102461)">
<rect width="240" height="144" rx="8" fill="url(#paint0_linear_105_102461)"/>
<path opacity="0.2" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M-28.6897 92.6764L61.0255 68.6372C69.0915 66.476 73.8782 58.1851 71.717 50.1191L47.6779 -39.596L14.6097 -58.688L-39.5345 35.0924C-41.5395 38.5653 -42.0828 42.6924 -41.045 46.5658L-28.6897 92.6764Z" fill="white"/>
<path opacity="0.2" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M207.941 180.677L297.656 156.638C305.722 154.477 310.508 146.186 308.347 138.12L284.308 48.405L251.24 29.313L197.096 123.093C195.091 126.566 194.547 130.693 195.585 134.567L207.941 180.677Z" fill="white"/>
</g>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear_105_102461" x1="0" y1="0" x2="257.595" y2="46.4717" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#0F3CF0"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#0C31C6"/>
</linearGradient>
<clipPath id="clip0_105_102461">
<rect width="240" height="144" rx="8" fill="white"/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: https://websemantics.uk/tools/svg-to-background-image-conversion/

Comment: https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to convert the `svg` image into a css background. You can do that by accessing [this](https://websemantics.uk/tools/svg-to-background-image-conversion/) tool. After you have the css background, you can normally apply it to the element in which you would want. That should do it!